Synchronized HashMap in multithreaded environment is not working
I have a scenario where I need the maximum size of my HashMap to be 10000. Any records inserted further should remove the oldest entry and proceed to insert. It is for a multithreaded scenario.
I am seeing a strange scenario, where the maximum limit exceeds. I can see the size keeps increasing more than 10000 (i.e) 20000+. Here is the code:
public class FixedSizeLinkedHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private final int maxSize;

    public FixedSizeLinkedHashMap(int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize, 0.75f, true);
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized V get(Object key) {
        return super.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized V remove(Object key) {
        return super.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void clear() {
        super.clear();
    }
}

In the calling class I have used
fixedsizeLhm = new FixedSizeLinkedHashMap<>(10000);

Is there anything I am missing?

Well, one possible explanation would be that you've not synchronized all of the methods that modify the map, e.g. merge(), computeIfAbsent() etc.

Synchronizing individual methods is not necessarily sufficient to make something thread-safe, especially not if there are methods in Map, AbstractMap, HashMap and LinkedHashMap that may be compound operations using those primitives you have overridden and made synchronized.

The correct way to accomplish this task is to remove all of your overrides except for removeEldestEntry, remove all use of the word synchronized, and then have your program wrap an instance of this Map in Collections.synchronizedMap:  fixedsizeLhm = Collections.synchronizedMap(new FixedSizeLinkedHashMap<>(10000));.  Also, pay attention to the example in that method’s documentation.  Merely synchronizing the methods is not enough!

Limiting the max size of a HashMap in Java

Assuming you've only tested using the declared methods of that class.
One obvious issue is the call to the size() method. Internally, this method returns an integer that is maintained through increment or decrement operations in methods like put() and remove(). This is clearly a thread-unsafe operation. You could improve this by maintaining an atomic counter within the class, which should lead to noticeable improvements.
BTW, it's more practical to use libraries like Guava or Caffeine.
